# Solving an Implicit Equation

Tags: python, scipy

How to correctly write the next line in the code: `chii = sp.optimize.fsolve(chiht(chi,3,1,1,1,1), 1)` ?
`T, a, b, gamma, beta` are parameters

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np

TC=315
H=1000

def chiht(chi, T, a, b, gamma, beta):
    global H, TC
    return a*(T-TC)*chi**(1/gamma)+b*chi**(1/gamma)*chi**(1/beta)*H**(1/beta)-1

chii = sp.optimize.fsolve(chiht(chi,3,1,1,1,1), 1)
print(chii)
print(chiht(chii,3,1,1,1,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `fsolve`. You're solving a scalar:

```py
from functools import partial
import scipy as sp


def chiht(
    chi: float, T: float, a: float, b: float, gamma: float, beta: float, H: float, TC: float,
) -> float:
    return (
        a*(T - TC)*chi**(1/gamma)
        + b * chi**(1/gamma) * chi**(1/beta) * H**(1/beta)
        - 1
    )


chiht_bound = partial(
    chiht,
    T=3, a=1, b=1, gamma=1, beta=1, H=315, TC=1_000,
)
chii = sp.optimize.root_scalar(f=chiht_bound, x0=1)
assert chii.converged
print(f'chii = {chii.root:.6e}')
print(f'err = {chiht_bound(chii.root):.1e}')
```

```
chii = -1.002691e-03
err = 2.2e-16
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you explain please why the answers in your solution and in the solution of Marc are different?

Comment: @MamMam The other error is over a quadrillion times higher than this error. So this is a solution to the equation and the other one isn't. As to why... I could try to look into it, but it'll be a comment on their answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the SciPy doc [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html):

> scipy.optimize.fsolve
>
> Return the roots of the (non-linear) equations defined by func(x) = 0
> given a starting estimate.
>
> Parameters: funccallable f(x, *args) A function that takes at least
> one (possibly vector) argument, and returns a value of the same
> length. [...]

You need to pass a function but here you are passing the result of this function (not the callable function itself) - or at least from the error message, Python is attempting to evaluate this function.

Try passing it as a lamdda function instead, this way:

```
TC = 315
H = 1000

def chiht(chi, T, a, b, gamma, beta):
    global H, TC
    return a*(T-TC)*chi**(1/gamma) + b*chi**(1/gamma)*chi**(1/beta)*H**(1/beta) - 1

chii = sp.optimize.fsolve(lambda chi: chiht(chi, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1), 1)

print(chii)
print(chiht(chii, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

Which outputs:

```
[1.70530257e-13]
[0.31517286]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain please why the answers in your solution  and in the solution of Reinderien are different? (Your solution: 1.70530257e-13 and 0.31517286, Reinderien's solution: -1.002691e-03 and 2.2e-16)

Comment: So no, your stated output is not the actual output of your routine - those two figures are swapped (thankfully), because the first value is the root and the _second_ value is the error. But this error (without changing the solver's tolerance) is higher than that of `root_scalar`, and `root_scalar` should be preferred anyway because... this is a scalar, not a vector.