# How to minimize a function by several parameters? (part 1)

Tags: python, scipy, minimize, minimization

I would like to minimize a function `dchi(a, b, c, d)` by 4 parameters `a`,`b`,`c` and `d`. 
It looks like there is an mistake in this line `res = sp.optimize.minimize(dchi, first_guess)`, could you please tell me what exactly is written incorrectly and how to fix it?

```
import functools
import scipy as sp


def CH(chi: float, T: float, a: float, b: float, c: float, d: float, H: float, TC: float, C:float) -> float:
    return (a*(T - TC)*chi**(1/c)+ b * chi**(1/c) * chi**(1/d) * H**(1/d)- 1)+C/(T-TC)


exp=[[10.0052, 87.9716], [11.0433, 86.3866], [12.359, 84.8015], [13.7127,   83.2164], [14.9939, 82.0276], [16.3367, 80.8388], [17.6282,   80.0463], [18.9464, 78.8575], [18.9934, 78.8575], [18.9969,   78.8575], [18.9962, 78.8575], [19.4221, 78.4612], [20.8034,   77.6687], [22.1306, 76.4799], [23.4352, 75.6873], [24.7503,   75.291], [26.0295, 74.4985], [27.3692, 73.706], [30.0264,   72.9134], [31.3262, 72.5172], [32.6313, 72.1209], [33.9404,   71.7246], [35.2494, 71.3284], [36.551, 70.9321], [37.8445,   70.5358], [40.5813, 69.7433], [41.7696, 69.347], [43.0624,   69.347], [44.3609, 68.9507], [45.6536, 68.5545], [46.9616,   68.5545], [48.254, 68.1582], [49.5428, 67.7619], [52.1298,   67.3657], [53.4147, 67.3657], [54.7091, 66.9694], [56.0001,   66.9694], [57.2883, 66.5731], [58.5865, 66.5731], [59.8911,   66.1769], [62.4856, 66.1769], [63.7665, 65.7806], [65.0689,   65.7806], [66.3588, 65.3843], [67.6581, 65.3843], [68.9546,   65.3843], [70.2572, 64.9881], [72.8482, 64.9881], [74.1637,   64.9881], [75.4546, 64.5918], [76.7495, 64.5918], [78.0347,   64.5918], [79.3376, 64.1955], [80.6437, 64.1955], [83.5861,   64.1955], [84.8957, 63.7993], [86.2123, 63.7993], [87.5317,   63.7993], [88.8468, 63.7993], [90.1674, 63.7993], [91.4775,   63.403], [94.2769, 63.403], [95.5863, 63.403], [96.9007,   63.403], [98.2013, 63.403], [99.523, 63.0067], [100.839,   63.0067], [102.147, 63.0067], [104.812, 63.0067], [106.131,   63.0067], [107.448, 62.6104], [108.789, 62.6104], [110.099,   62.6104], [111.414, 62.6104], [112.756, 62.6104], [115.404,   62.6104], [116.737, 62.6104], [118.059, 62.6104], [119.376,   62.2142], [120.7, 62.2142], [122.025, 62.2142], [123.367,   62.2142], [126.006, 62.2142], [127.352, 62.2142], [128.674,   62.2142], [129.999, 62.2142], [131.333, 62.2142], [132.652,   61.8179], [133.987, 61.8179], [136.652, 61.8179], [137.987,   61.8179], [139.324, 61.8179], [140.645, 61.8179], [141.989,   61.8179], [143.316, 61.8179], [144.646, 61.8179], [147.323,   61.8179], [148.651, 61.4216], [149.978, 61.4216], [151.303,   61.4216], [152.637, 61.4216], [153.949, 61.4216], [155.268,   61.4216], [157.929, 61.4216], [159.252, 61.4216], [160.581,   61.0254], [161.889, 61.0254], [163.219, 61.0254], [164.546,   61.0254], [165.873, 61.0254], [168.524, 61.0254], [169.852,   60.6291], [171.173, 60.6291], [172.494, 60.6291], [173.83,   60.6291], [175.16, 60.6291], [176.473, 60.6291], [179.122,   60.2328], [180.459, 60.2328], [181.78, 60.2328], [183.106,   59.8366], [184.439, 59.8366], [185.757, 59.8366], [187.079,   59.8366], [189.73, 59.4403], [191.06, 59.4403], [192.386,   59.044], [193.717, 59.044], [195.037, 59.044], [196.372,   58.6478], [197.693, 58.6478], [200.361, 58.2515], [201.689,   57.8552], [203.008, 57.8552], [204.335, 57.459], [205.651,   57.459], [206.996, 57.0627], [208.324, 57.0627], [210.977,   56.6664], [212.292, 56.2702], [213.602, 55.8739], [214.947,   55.8739], [216.259, 55.4776], [217.583, 55.0813], [218.895,   55.0813], [221.56, 54.2888], [222.865, 53.8925], [224.195,   53.4963], [225.505, 53.1], [226.824, 53.1], [228.192,   52.7037], [229.508, 52.3075], [232.191, 51.5149], [233.507,   51.1187], [234.836, 50.7224], [236.161, 50.3261], [237.479,   49.9299], [238.807, 49.5336], [240.13, 48.741], [242.774,   47.9485], [244.096, 47.5522], [245.417, 47.156], [246.74,   46.7597], [248.057, 46.3634], [249.382, 45.5709], [250.457,   46.2508], [251.117, 46.0365], [252.897, 45.4166], [253.112,   45.3033], [254.115, 44.9356], [255.112, 44.5707], [256.107,   44.2179], [257.936, 43.554], [259.077, 43.1208], [260.395,   42.633], [260.555, 42.5688], [261.881, 42.0749], [263.515,   41.4803], [264.389, 41.108], [264.559, 41.047], [264.724,   40.9939], [264.891, 40.9305], [265.058, 40.8548], [265.219,   40.807], [265.384, 40.7401], [265.549, 40.6799], [265.707,   40.6116], [265.872, 40.5381], [266.041, 40.4919], [266.218,   40.4131], [266.379, 40.365], [266.532, 40.2826], [266.705,   40.2386], [266.876, 40.1762], [267.038, 40.1109], [267.201,   40.0532], [267.373, 39.9972], [267.543, 39.9247], [267.71,   39.8555], [267.874, 39.7915], [268.035, 39.7336], [268.194,   39.6811], [268.367, 39.6056], [268.542, 39.5387], [268.705,   39.4762], [268.866, 39.3997], [269.029, 39.3423], [269.201,   39.2861], [269.374, 39.22], [269.539, 39.1538], [269.698,   39.0823], [269.87, 39.0231], [270.036, 38.9709], [270.194,   38.8925], [270.371, 38.8394], [270.536, 38.7638], [270.697,   38.7051], [270.868, 38.6425], [271.038, 38.574], [271.208,   38.5115], [271.367, 38.4455], [271.54, 38.3782], [271.711,   38.3156], [271.868, 38.2524], [272.03, 38.1917], [272.2,   38.1262], [272.361, 38.0706], [272.525, 38.0021], [274.156,   37.3821], [274.229, 37.3188], [274.362, 37.27], [274.524,   37.2048], [274.705, 37.1411], [274.877, 37.0827], [275.029,   37.0104], [275.196, 36.9607], [275.37, 36.8851], [275.526,   36.8172], [275.683, 36.7629], [275.855, 36.6982], [276.025,   36.6346], [276.185, 36.5695], [276.345, 36.5063], [276.506,   36.4347], [276.68, 36.3789], [276.845, 36.315], [277.012,   36.2632], [277.184, 36.1689], [277.35, 36.1295], [277.517,   36.0462], [277.676, 35.9975], [277.839, 35.9304], [278.009,   35.8579], [278.18, 35.8111], [278.341, 35.7453], [278.5,   35.6707], [278.67, 35.6269], [278.836, 35.5542], [279.005,   35.486], [279.176, 35.4266], [279.333, 35.3622], [279.502,   35.2938], [279.671, 35.2304], [279.833, 35.1688], [279.997,   35.1014], [280.169, 35.0437], [280.337, 34.9787], [280.498,   34.9181], [280.67, 34.8453], [280.837, 34.7763], [280.995,   34.7195], [281.164, 34.6492], [281.332, 34.5889], [281.5,   34.523], [281.664, 34.4628], [281.83, 34.3953], [282.004,   34.3438], [282.164, 34.2835], [282.324, 34.214], [282.493,   34.1503], [282.67, 34.087], [282.833, 34.0348], [282.996,   33.9549], [283.164, 33.9051], [284.809, 33.291], [284.864,   33.2491], [284.993, 33.1839], [285.16, 33.111], [285.323,   33.0541], [285.487, 32.9876], [285.655, 32.9227], [285.821,   32.8639], [285.991, 32.8064], [286.164, 32.7342], [286.329,   32.6806], [286.494, 32.606], [286.66, 32.562], [286.824,   32.4928], [286.985, 32.4283], [287.149, 32.3634], [287.321,   32.2873], [287.487, 32.2322], [287.644, 32.1765], [287.817,   32.1208], [287.988, 32.0552], [288.146, 31.9866], [288.306,   31.9345], [288.476, 31.8621], [288.646, 31.8045], [288.815,   31.7536], [288.985, 31.6971], [289.14, 31.6201], [289.307,   31.551], [289.481, 31.4893], [289.645, 31.444], [289.81,   31.3815], [289.975, 31.311], [290.141, 31.252], [290.306,   31.1829], [290.466, 31.1326], [290.636, 31.0702], [290.807,   31.011], [290.967, 30.9446], [291.139, 30.8823], [291.304,   30.8283], [291.47, 30.7563], [291.646, 30.706], [291.809,   30.6516], [291.974, 30.578], [292.141, 30.5155], [292.306,   30.4571], [292.47, 30.3986], [292.634, 30.3283], [292.805,   30.2715], [292.971, 30.212], [293.127, 30.1523], [293.299,   30.0891], [293.475, 30.0263], [293.634, 29.9634], [293.794,   29.9016], [295.41, 29.3469], [295.467, 29.2859], [295.612,   29.2319], [295.787, 29.1886], [295.954, 29.1198], [296.116,   29.0857], [296.277, 29.0178], [296.445, 28.9598], [296.617,   28.9062], [296.78, 28.8415], [296.946, 28.7719], [297.111,   28.7037], [297.277, 28.6442], [297.444, 28.5661], [297.603,   28.5065], [297.772, 28.438], [297.945, 28.3781], [298.11,   28.3183], [298.27, 28.2553], [298.436, 28.1991], [298.608,   28.1362], [298.775, 28.089], [298.934, 28.0215], [299.089,   27.9536], [299.26, 27.8898], [299.431, 27.8379], [299.596,   27.7736], [299.77, 27.7224], [299.939, 27.6707], [300.1,   27.6075], [300.268, 27.5584], [300.436, 27.4834], [300.595,   27.445], [300.761, 27.3805], [300.928, 27.3191], [301.085,   27.2599], [301.248, 27.2049], [301.416, 27.1372], [301.582,   27.0904], [301.742, 27.0381], [301.902, 26.9595], [302.077,   26.9182], [302.254, 26.8639], [302.409, 26.7965], [302.573,   26.751], [302.744, 26.6902], [302.904, 26.6289], [303.075,   26.5635], [303.24, 26.5116], [303.398, 26.4599], [303.571,   26.3952], [303.75, 26.3447], [303.915, 26.2879], [304.07,   26.2416], [304.236, 26.1701], [304.396, 26.1088]]

#print(exp[0][0])

def dchi(a, b, c, d):
    sd=0
    for i in range(len(exp)):
        CH_bound = functools.partial(CH, T=exp[i][0], a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, H=315, TC=1000, C=2)
        ch1 = sp.optimize.root_scalar(f=CH_bound, x0=0)
        sd=sd+(ch1.root - exp[i][1]) ** 2
    return sd

#print(dchi(1,1,1,1))

first_guess = [1,1,1,1]
res = sp.optimize.minimize(dchi, first_guess)

#print(res)
```

the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\main.py", line 23, in <module>
    res = sp.optimize.minimize(dchi, first_guess)
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 705, in minimize
    res = _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py", line 1419, in _minimize_bfgs
    sf = _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac, args=args, epsilon=eps,
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py", line 383, in _prepare_scalar_function
    sf = ScalarFunction(fun, x0, args, grad, hess,
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py", line 158, in __init__
    self._update_fun()
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py", line 251, in _update_fun
    self._update_fun_impl()
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py", line 155, in update_fun
    self.f = fun_wrapped(self.x)
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py", line 137, in fun_wrapped
    fx = fun(np.copy(x), *args)
TypeError: dchi() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'b', 'c', and 'd'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is this related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77284000/solving-an-implicit-equation ?

Comment: try ```res = sp.optimize.minimize(lambda x: dchi(*x), first_guess)``` though this results in an unsuccessful optimisation due to NaNs.

Comment: You aren't checking whether your inner root-finding converges, so that eventually fails. Also, since the root for `chi` tends to be negative, this will only be well-behaved if `chi` is coerced to a complex number and then the absolute of the error figure is returned.

Comment: @Reinderien, thanks! I have added the errores

Comment: Please link the article you referenced.

Comment: @Reinderien, thanks! This article [link](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jap/article-abstract/111/7/07A334/391588/The-effect-of-distributed-exchange-parameters-on?redirectedFrom=fulltext). It can be downloaded here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rDXYsWNUpqXJ1VxcNVwsXrOd1hwj4RUy/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Reinderien, formula (2) from the article is used in the code along with the Curie-Weiss law (С/(T-TC), where C is Curie constant (1 in the code) an TC is Curie temperature (315 in the code)), H is magnetic field (1000 Oe in the code), a, b, c, d is parameteres a, b, gamma, betta from the article. Experimental data in the code is dependence of magnetic susceptibility (chi = M/H) on temperature (T). The formula (2) describes the high-temperature dependence, and Curie’s law describes the low-temperature part in our case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve at least a couple of your problems, use a complex, properly unpack your parameters, and check root convergence:

```py
import functools

import numpy as np
import scipy as sp


def CH(
    chi: float, T: float, a: float, b: float, c: float, d: float, H: float, TC: float, C: float,
) -> float:
    chi = chi + 0j
    err = (
        a*(T - TC)*chi**(1/c)
        + b * chi**(1/c) * chi**(1/d) * H**(1/d)
        + C/(T-TC)
        - 1
    )
    return np.abs(err)


exp = (
    (10.0052, 87.9716), (11.0433, 86.3866), (12.359, 84.8015),
    (169.852,   60.6291), (171.173, 60.6291), (172.494, 60.6291), (173.83,   60.6291),
)


def dchi(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    a, b, c, d = params
    sd = 0
    x0 = 0
    for exp_a, exp_b in exp:
        CH_bound = functools.partial(CH, T=exp_a, a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, H=315, TC=1000, C=2)
        ch1 = sp.optimize.root_scalar(
            f=CH_bound, x0=x0,
        )
        assert ch1.converged
        sd += (ch1.root - exp_b)**2
        x0 = ch1.root
    return sd


first_guess = (1,1,1,1)
res = sp.optimize.minimize(
    fun=dchi,
    x0=first_guess,
)
assert res.success, res.message
print(res.x)
```

This does get further, but in context your function is problematic and eventually doesn't converge. Are there bounds on any of the variables you've shown? You really do need to find out what these should be.

Anyway, it's a bad idea to run an inner root-find. You should be running a single upper-level `minimize` with a vectorized root constraint; and don't loop.

With your chi function as

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import NonlinearConstraint, minimize


def CH(
    chi: np.ndarray, T: float, H: float, TC: float, C: float, a: float, b: float, c: float, d: float,
) -> np.ndarray:
    err = (
        a*(T - TC)*chi**(1/c)
        + b * chi**(1/c) * chi**(1/d) * H**(1/d)
        + C/(T-TC)
        - 1
    )
    return err
```

then a (slow, but) successful optimization can look like

```
def dchi(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    chi = params[4:]
    chi_err = chi - exp_chi
    err = chi_err.dot(chi_err)
    return err

def dchi_jac(params: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    chi = params[4:]
    jac = np.zeros_like(params)
    jac[4:] = 2*(chi - exp_chi)
    return jac

def dchi_root(params: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    # for each value of exp_T, there is some unknown optimal value of chi such that
    # CH(chi, T) == 0
    abcd, chi = np.split(params, (4,))
    a, b, c, d = abcd
    root_err = CH(
        chi=chi, T=exp_T, a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, H=315, TC=1000, C=2,
    )
    return root_err

exp_T, exp_chi = np.array(exp).T
first_guess = np.concatenate((
    (0.79, 0.00893, 0.428, 1.38),
    exp_chi,
))
result = minimize(
    fun=dchi, jac=dchi_jac,
    x0=first_guess,
    constraints=NonlinearConstraint(
        fun=dchi_root,
        lb=0, ub=0,
    ),
    options={'maxiter': 10, 'disp': True},
)
print(result.message)
print(f'Chi error: {result.fun:.3f}')
print(f'Root error: {np.abs(dchi_root(result.x)).sum():.3f}')
print(f'Parameters: {result.x[:4]}')
```

```
Iteration limit reached    (Exit mode 9)
            Current function value: 1543.01943809294
            Iterations: 10
            Function evaluations: 16
            Gradient evaluations: 10
Iteration limit reached
Chi error: 1543.019
Root error: 57.920
Parameters: [-1.61941337e-05 -7.62007792e-06  6.02274220e-01  1.32563818e+00]
```

This will do better if you give it more iterations to run, and especially if you write a second Jacobian for the root.

Comment: Thank you! I can’t say for sure about the bounds, but I have numbers from a certain article where the authors used this formula. In their case the parametes are `a=0.79`, `b=0.00893`, `c=0.428`, `d=1.38`, but in my case the parameters may differ. In the code `exp` is an experimental data, where the first number in each pair is the temperature, the second number in each pair is the experimental value of ch1 for particular temperature. In the code, I would like to find the best parameter values for the best fit of the experimental data obtained using the formula.

Comment: Originally, I have a lot more experimental values, I added them all to the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation!

Comment: Reinderien, could you please help me with a code modification. Now I would like to rewrite code in such a way that 2 more parameters (TC and C) are added to the existing 4 parameters (a,b,c,d). Do I understand correctly that I need to change the following lines: in `def dchi` it is needed to change 4 on 6 in expression `chi = params[6:]` (`chi = params[6:]`); in `def dchi_jac` next changes: 4->6 (`chi = params[6:],... jac[6:] = 2*(chi - exp_chi`))

Comment: in `def dchi_root` add new 2 parameters (TC and C) and chnge 4 ->6: `def dchi_root(params: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:     abcd, chi = np.split(params, (6,))     a, b, c, d,TC,C = abcd     root_err = CH(         chi=chi, T=exp_T, a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, H=315, TC=TC, C=C,     )     return root_err; add two initial values: first_guess = np.concatenate((     (0.79, 0.00893, 0.428, 1.38, 315, 1),     exp_chi, ))` and in print 4->6 `print(f'Parameters: {result.x[:6]}')`

Comment: Please create a new question.

Comment: Reinderien, thanks! I have created the question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77317213/how-to-minimize-a-function-by-several-parameters-part-2)